# Is OpenERP skinnable?

Tags: open-source, erp, odoo

I've looked at the site of OpenERP and Google and have not found any reference to skins for OpenERP. I understand that the logo must be maintained but if I want to improve their appearance, is there any way to create skins?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: IT may help you..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izz7XD3QNHc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 6.0 web client layout (images and css) are in a folder like `...\openerp\web-client\addons\openerp\static`. In 6.1 you can find the equivalent content at somewhere like `...\openerp\openerp-web\addons\web\static`.

I believe that a ZIP file with a replacement for those folders could considered a skin.

Answer (score 4):

override css classes. you can override css for each modules if you want. the main css is here->
openerp-7.0\openerp\addons\web\static\src\css

after addons folder every module can have own css,

openerp-7.0\openerp\addons\SOME_MODULE\static\src\css

it overrides main css.

Answer (score 3):

changing the existing css and images can lead to update incompatible.
in openerp 6.1 you can add a module in web addons . and change the behavior of the existing css, images.

at time of starting server you just have to pass "--load=web,WEB_THEME_MODULE"

Answer (score 1):

Making use of the web framework in version 6.1 I've set out to write a simple module to change basic css and images. You can find this module here http://apps.openerp.com/addon/7961.

The basic is working well but it is a work in progress as I hope to extend it in scope and fix minor issues. The source code is available in Launchpad for anyone to report bugs, or better yet, contribute some code. Find it here as [web_theme](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~poiesis-consulting/openobject-poiesis/trunk/files).